# Thread-safe caching in ASP.NET HttpModules

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, caching, thread-safety, httpmodule

### Here's the scenario

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 application which has a LOT of legacy URL rewrites. I want to build an HTTP module that will look at a database of these rewrites and do a 301 redirect if needed. There's tens of thousands of records in this table.

So obviously I need to do some sort of caching so I'm not hitting the database and searching through all those records for each page request.

One of our requirements is to have a fast start up time when our application recycles for some reason (worker process recycles or what have you). So I don't want to load the whole table at app start up. The app start up is already excruciatingly slow.

My brilliant/ridiculous idea is to,

1. At app start up in my HttpModule create an empty dictionary to hold rewrites.
2. Start a background worker thread. The app continues starting up.
3. The background worker thread updates the dictionary with say, oh, the most 1000 most used rewrites.

### Questions

My questions are:

1. Is this ridiculous?
2. Is there such a thing as
   a thread-safe dictionary? The
   background thread might be updating
   the dictionary while new requests
   are coming in.
3. Would all the locking
   that goes on in a thread-safe
   collection slow down incoming requests?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're targeting .NET 4.0, you can use [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) and it will take care of all the magic for you in terms of concurrency. Just use the `GetOrAdd` for incoming requests and `AddOrUpdate` for your background population idea.

I would also like to pose something for you to think about as well. If you've got these thousands of URLs are you really only running on one server? I ask that because you're only talking about a local caching scheme here. If you have three servers all of them are going to be pounding the DB for the URL data. Are you looking into a distributed caching technology like Windows Server AppFabric or Memcached?